# Syncing Data between multiple android devices with 1 google account

Tags: android, synchronization, google-cloud-messaging

Good day,
I really hope someone can help me with this.
I'm having difficulties trying to sync data between 2 devices. Google Cloud messaging seems like the thing I want to use, and I've played with the tutorial. However I had the following questions:

- I'm broadcasting commands to all users.. How do I send messages to a specific user?
- How do I send data back to the webserver?
- Is this the correct way of syncing data between multiple devices using the same google account?

The data will really be a small amount, so I do not need a massive server to accomplish it, and the 4KB limit on GCM will be more than enough.

PS I'm using Android studio.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm broadcasting commands to all users.. How do I send messages to a specific user?

Each device has specific registration ID. You can specify a particular registration ID and ask Google to send the Push. See [Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) example for that.

> How do I send data back to the webserver?

If you want to send the data from device to your 3rd party server, you can either send it via HTTP or you can use [device-to-cloud feature](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) of GCM Cloud Connection Server.

> Is this the correct way of syncing data between multiple devices using the same Google account?

I think the way you are going, you can accomplish what you want. I'm not aware of better alternatives though. Also, [How to sync data between different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686400/how-to-sync-data-between-different-devices) might help.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer! Secondly, using the GCM server might cause timing issues if I understood the server link correctly. It seems there might be a massive delay between messages as the server load increases(because of the flow control). Is this something I should be worrying about?